# Append items to an observable array in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I have a service that fetches documents and list their metadata on a page which works fine. I want to implement "infinite scrolling" and looked at [npm i angular2-infinite-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-infinite-scroll)

At the moment I'm using an observable for the documents and the async pipe in an `*ngFor` loop

**document-list.ts**

```
export class DocumentList implements OnInit {
    documents: Observable<Array<Document>>;
    chunck: number = 100;
    from: number = 0;
    keyword: string = "";

    constructor(private _documentService: DocumentService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    this.documents = this._documentService.getDocuments(this.chunck, this.from, this.keyword);
    }
}
```

With angular2-infinite-scroll I have a function that's called when I scroll to the bottom of the page, what I am trying to do is to fetch more documents and present their metadata on the page with what's already there

```
onScroll() {
this.from = documents.length ... ?
//this.documents = this._documentService.getDocuments(this.chunck, this.from, this.keyword);
}
```

I am not sure if this is possible when I'm using an observable? If I use a simple array for documents instead `documents: Document[]` I can do something like

```
onScroll() {
this._documentService.getDocuments(this.chunck, this.from, this.keyword)
    .subscribe(documents => this.documents.push(documents));
}
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with a Subject rather than an Observable. I would try something like...

For your DocumentsService:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class DocumentService {
  _documentSubject = Subject.create();

  getNextTen() {
    // ... get the document meta data however ... 
    this._documentSubject.next(documentMetaData);
  }

  get documentSubject() {
    return this._documentSubject;
  }

  //...
}
```

And then on your documents component, you'd do:

```
 // ...
documents: Array = [];
documentRetriever: Subject<any>;

constructor(ds: DocumentService) {
  //You maybe shouldn't do this in the constructor, but the point is
  //you only want to subscribe to the Subject once.
  this.documentRetriver = ds.documentSubject;
  this.documentRetriever.subscribe(newDocuments => {
    this.documents.push(newDocuments);
  })
}
onScroll() {
  this.ds.getNextTen();
}
```

Because of the nature of RxJS Subjects (they act as both Observables and Observers), you can pass data via .next() outside of the creation of the Observable.

You may or may not still need to use the async pipe when binding to the documents array.

For more info on Subjects:

[ReactiveX Docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)

[Getting started with RxJS: Subjects](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/subjects.html)

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look into this and come back